# Auto-fill problem with my table generator

Tags: javascript

I'm trying make `table` generator for HTML with JavaScript. When I tried generate, the first field is created successfully. But auto-filling doesn't work correctly.

[image: Error with image]

How can I solve this problem?

My Library code:

```js
export default class Table {
  #maxlength
  constructor(body) {
    this.body = body
    this.parent = document.createElement('table')
    this.body.append(this.parent)
    this.#maxlength = 0;
  }
  add(...values) {
    let element = document.createElement('tr')
    let elname = this.parent.childElementCount < 1 ? "th" : "td"
    function add(value) {
      let addval = document.createElement(elname)
      addval.textContent = value
      element.append(addval)
    }
    [...values].map(el => {
      add(el)
    })
    if(this.#maxlength - [...values].length > 0) {
      new Array(this.#maxlength - [...values].length).map(el => {
      add("")
    })
      
    }
    if (this.#maxlength < [...values].length) {
      this.#maxlength = [...values].length
    }
    this.parent.append(element)
  }
}
```

My HTML Javascript:

```js
import Table from './Table.js'

const { body } = document;

let table = new Table(body)
table.add("a","a","a")
table.add("a","a","a")
table.add("a","a","a")
table.add("a","a") // AUTOFILLING
table.add("a") // AUTOFILLING
table.add("a","a") // AUTOFILLING
table.add("a","a","a")
```

Comment: Surely the empty areas lack cells because you didn't set any. Is there some reason why you can't place empty strings in your argument list?: `table.add("a", "a", "")`. Possibly even leaving the argument undefined but there might also work: `table.add("a", "a",)` - that is, place a trailing comma. Sorry if I've misunderstood what you're doing.

Comment: Hello, this solution works for non created cells but this cells becomes wrapped and i want if data is n/a code fill automaticly himself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears you were creating the `th` or `td` elements but they were never added to the `tr` element. I believe this was primarily due to the fact that you weren't actually appending the empty entries into `values` as intended. Comparing `values.length` to `this.#maxlength` in a `while` loop resolves this issue as seen in the code snippet below:

```js
class Table {
  #maxlength;
  constructor(body) {
    this.body = body;
    this.parent = document.createElement('table');
    this.body.append(this.parent);
    this.#maxlength = 0;
  }
  add(...values) {
    let element = document.createElement('tr');
    let elname = this.parent.childElementCount < 1 ? "th" : "td";
    // Add blank entries for null values
    while (values.length < this.#maxlength) {
      values.push("");
    }

    function add(value) {
      let addval = document.createElement(elname);
      addval.textContent = value;
      element.append(addval);
    }
    [...values].forEach(el => {
      add(el);
    });
    if (this.#maxlength - [...values].length > 0) {
      new Array(this.#maxlength - [...values].length).forEach(el => {
        add("");
      });
    }
    if (this.#maxlength < [...values].length) {
      this.#maxlength = [...values].length;
    }
    this.parent.append(element);
  }
}

const {
  body
} = document;

let table = new Table(body);
table.add("a", "a", "a");
table.add("a", "a", "a");
table.add("a", "a", "a");
table.add("a", "a"); // AUTOFILLING
table.add("a"); // AUTOFILLING
table.add("a", "a"); // AUTOFILLING
table.add("a", "a", "a");
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

th,
td {
  width: 1.5rem;
}
```

Comment: @Wraithdev2 If this helped solve the issue, don't forget to mark this answer as the accepted answer.